# Setting TaskCompletionSource result in RelayCommand not triggering awaited code

Tags: c#, async-await, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

Edit2: I tracked down the problem to an unrelated issue (the view and the logic were looking at different ViewModel instances. oops.)

I have the following code in a WinUI 3 application, using CommunityToolkit.MVVM, trying to use `TaskCompletionSource` with `RelayCommand` to control application flow around user input. It's working in one spot, and not in another. I cannot for the life of me tell what I'm doing differently in the second that would cause it to fail like this.

Edit: Following up on Andrew's answer, I've discovered it works fine if I call the Next method from code, rather than from the UI (using the generated NextCommand.) I still don't know why it works for the first one and not the second. I've tried using both `ConfigureAwait(false)` and `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`, to no avail.

```cs
//App.xaml.cs
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();
    m_window.Activate();

    _ = RunGame();
}

private async Task RunGame()
{
    // ... create start view ...

    var settings = await startView.ViewModel.WaitForStartAsync(); //This works

    // ... create first game step ...
        
    await currentStep.WaitForNextAsync(); //This doesn't

    Exit(); //never called
}

//StartViewModel.cs
public partial class StartViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //settings logic

    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<GameSettings> m_taskCompletionSource = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Start() => m_taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(new(Difficulty));

    public Task<GameSettings> WaitForStartAsync() => m_taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

//GameStepViewModel.cs
public abstract partial class GameStepViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty, NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor("NextCommand")]
    private bool m_nextEnabled = true;

    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _tcs = new();

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = "NextEnabled")]
    private void Next() => _tcs.TrySetResult();

    public Task WaitForNextAsync() => _tcs.Task;
}
```

edit: I know from debugging that the `Next()` method is being called successfully and the `TaskCompletionSource.Task` is transitioning to `RanToCompletion`.

Comment: Are you sure the posted code reproduces the problem? Could `RunGame` be completing with an exception?

Comment: Could you try initializing the `TaskCompletionSource` with the `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` option, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @StephenCleary setting a breakpoint on the second await shows it definitely gets to that point.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias just tried that, doesn't change anything.

Comment: I created a test project adding some missing code but it works (**Exit** is called after **Next** is called).

Comment: But I have to say that I'm not sure if using `TaskCompletionSource` or having a **RunGame** method like this is a good approach. Consider doing this in a way that you  don't need to put code in App.xaml.cs.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding is there anything in particular you added that might be making the difference? I've used the same pattern in other projects without issue, and I'm truly baffled why it doesn't work here.
I'm not particularly attached to the code being there, it could just as easily be in MainWindow or some dedicated ViewModel or something, although I don't see any way to avoid having to eventually transition from synchronous code to asynchronous. I just want to avoid having to use a pile of callbacks for transitioning from user input to program logic and back.

Comment: Posted the code from my test project that worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that worked (Exit() called after Next() is called) for me.

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    _window = new MainWindow();
    _window.Activate();

    _ = RunGame();
}

private async Task RunGame()
{
    var startView = new StartView();
    _window.Content = startView;
    var settings = await startView.ViewModel.WaitForStartAsync();
    var firstGameStep = new FirstGameStep();
    firstGameStep.CallNextLater(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    await firstGameStep.WaitForNextAsync();
    Exit();
}
```

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskCompletionSourceExample;

public enum Difficulty
{
    Easy,
    Medium,
    Hard
}

public class GameSettings
{
    public GameSettings(Difficulty difficulty)
    {
    }
}

public partial class StartViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<GameSettings> m_taskCompletionSource = new();

    private Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }

    public Task<GameSettings> WaitForStartAsync() => m_taskCompletionSource.Task;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Start() => m_taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(new(Difficulty));
}

public sealed partial class StartView : Page
{
    public StartView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public StartViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}

public class FirstGameStep : GameStepViewModel
{
    public FirstGameStep()
    {
        NextEnabled = false;
    }
}

public abstract partial class GameStepViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public void CallNextLater(TimeSpan delay)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(delay);
            NextEnabled = true;
            Next();
        });
    }

    [ObservableProperty, NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor("NextCommand")]
    private bool m_nextEnabled = true;

    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _tcs = new();

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = "NextEnabled")]
    private void Next() => _tcs.TrySetResult();

    public Task WaitForNextAsync() => _tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you call Next via the Command in UI? I've gotten mine to work using your example method, a delayed call triggered via the main logic flow, but it still doesn't work when I click the button (despite Next() being called correctly)...

Comment: I added a `Button` on `StartView` and bound it to the `NextCommand` and it worked. So it should work if `Next` is called from the UI thread or not.